# action links text in facebook post to wall dialog using javascript not working

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I trying to bulid  a facebook application using javascript.In my application, the user gets the result and a dialog after  a time delay popup. Everthing is working well except one here's my code for the 'post to wall dialog'

```
<script>
var publish = {
  method: 'stream.publish',
  display: 'popup', // force popup mode
  attachment: {
    name: 'Connect',
    caption: 'The Facebook Connect JavaScript SDK',
actions: [{ name: 'action_links text!', link: 'http://www.example.com' }],
    description: (
      'A small JavaScript library that allows you to harness ' +
      'the power of Facebook, bringing the user\'s identity, ' +
      'social graph and distribution power to your site.'
    ),
    href: 'http://www.example.com/'

  }
};

FB.ui(publish, Log.info.bind('stream.publish callback'));
</script>
```

The line containing  actions not working for me.Can anyone just inform what is the solution for this...

Answer (score 1):

The property should be called action_links not actions and only have text and href values. Use something like:

```
action_links: [{ text: 'action link test', href: 'http://example.com'}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that the action must be defined through the fb web interface for the app!