# Facebook feed format text

Tags: facebook, feed

is it possible to format the description text so that I can display an unordered list?

```
  ul-tag seems not to work.
```

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/feed-dialog/v2.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Afaik it´s not possible at all to format the feed message in any way, or to include HTML tags.

You can try action links as described in this thread, but i am not sure if they still work with the feed dialog: [action links text in facebook post to wall dialog using javascript not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6137761/action-links-text-in-facebook-post-to-wall-dialog-using-javascript-not-working)